# Node.js version v16.20.2 detected. The Angular CLI requires a minimum of v18.13

Tags: node.js, macos, angular-cli, nvm

I'm getting this warning despite not having node 16 installed:

```
Node.js version v16.20.2 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum of v18.13.
```

I've force-removed node from brew:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node
```

and reinstalled angular:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

installed node versions:

```
❯ nvm ls
->      v21.6.2
         system
default -> 21.6.2 (-> v21.6.2)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v21.6.2) (default)
stable -> 21.6 (-> v21.6.2) (default)
lts/* -> lts/iron (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.2 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.19.1 (-> N/A)
lts/iron -> v20.11.1 (-> N/A)
```

I've been trying to play around with `node`, `nvm` and `angular-cli` but can't get rid of the warning. The warning gets displayed with each new terminal instance which gets really annoying.

I'm on `apple silicon` with `ventura 13.2.1` if that matters.

### Edit:

If I uninstall angular, the warning still shows somehow.

Comment: How did you install `node`? `which node` will tell you where it is installed and you may be able to upgrade it.

Comment: originally i installed node with brew but since i had the problem i uninstalled it and used nvm instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. nvm install 18.13.0
2. nvm alias default 18.13.0

Then try to run angular app.

Comment: Done. still the same warning is shown. No idea what's going on

Comment: what's funny is if i uninstall angular, the warning is still shown

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Is it possible that you have a specific version pinned in a ` .nvmrc` file?

Comment: Try `which angular` and `which node` after you uninstall Angular CLI.

Comment: result: `angular not found` and `/Users/[user_name]/.nvm/versions/node/v21.6.2/bin/node`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).